7 circles theorem
If 7 circles satisfy the conditions of the 7 circles theorem, is it sufficient to know the centers of 5 circles to reconstruct all of them?

Is there a way to calculate or construct the other two circles if only five centers are given?

Welcome to Math.SE! ... Rather than require people to visit another site to understand what you're asking, please include relevant details in the body of the question itself. (Note that comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) In this case, state the conditions of the 7 Circles Theorem. ... Also, the community prefers/expects a question to include efforts made by the asker. (What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?) This helps people tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand. ... Good luck!

If I had the permission to add images to the question, I would add it directly. Explaining it in words without a drawing is meaningless.

No: for example with the five black circles below, the other two could be the red circles or the light blue circles or many other possibilities.

This also illustrates the $7$-circles theorem, in that with an initial circle, and six other circles that they are tangential both to the original circle and their two neighbours, then the three lines joining opposite points of tangency are concurrent in a point. Here there is a different concurrent point when using the red circles and when using the light blue circles.

What if the 5 circles with fixed centers are the external ones (those that are tangential to only two others)?

The inner circle is much more constrained than the outer ones, so it seems that this freedom of continuously changing the diameters of the two is no longer there in this case.

Vosoni, indeed and I suspect if two missing outer circles were not adjacent you would also lose the flexibility.

Yes, and there will be clearly situations that have no solutions. So my question is, in a situation where there is one solution (or a discrete number of them), how to find one? Can one do anything better than brute-force geometric constraint solver?

@Vosoni Perhaps.  Given the initial circle and four other circles as shown, you have four points of tangency on the initial circle, two of which form an opposite pair and so a fixed line segment for the theorem.  Choose an arbitrary point on this line segment.  The theorem then tells you where the missing two points of tangency on the initial circle are.  That should be enough to fix the two missing circles, and there may be a construction (certainly in my illustration where the five known circles are congruent).

@Vosoni from your comments it seems to me that your problem is slightly different from what you're asking in the question. Isn't it? I think to have an answer to your last comment - how to construct 7 circles satisfying the theorem, if some of the circles are given.

Not circles but their centers only. It is unknown to which circles the centers belong. You just have 5 points on a plane and the question is, how to construct the 7 circles from them. All 7 radii and the centers of the remaining two circles are unknown variables.

@Henry Your comment assumes that I know the radii of all circles, but I don't. They need to be calculated somehow. That can be done by writing a system of equations, but here will be many such systems depending on which circles are missing. Then I could see which ones have solutions. E.g. I first assume that all 5 circles are the outer circles. This implies 5 possibilities for where the missing outer circle can be (between which two of the given ones), then I must write a system of equations with 7 radii and 4 components of unknown center coordinates as variables. Not sure if this is solvable.

@Vosoni I assumed you knew everything about five of the circles (in particular position and size) and nothing about the other two.  There will be cases, as in the diagram, where there are an infinite number of solutions, and cases where there are a finite number of solutions (for example if you adapted the diagram knowing the four outer black circles and one red circle I think there would be two solutions, while knowing the four outer black circles and one blue circle there would be one solution).

Yes, that's how it is. I see it as a geometric constraint equation with parameters. As with ordinary equations, sometimes there are multiple solutions or none at all. I see nothing wrong with that. That does not answer the question, how to solve it. So far I don't know even how to approach the problem in the simplest case when the solution is unique.

Where there are a finite number of solutions - i.e. when the missing circles include the initial circle or two non-adjacent later circles - you have a version of Apollonius's problem which is well studied.

Thank you! This reference is very useful, I didn't know about this one. Will read about it more. At first glance, though, Apollonius's problem is different because there 3 circles are fixed. In my version of the problem I am looking for a circle that is tangent to 5 other circles whose radii can be varied.
